IBM AppID use original page window for authentication page instead of pop up window
I have an SPA and it is authenticated using ibm app id. However it displays a external pop up page for the authentication. Is there anyway I can implement the authentication without using popup? Something like display it on a new tab instead of displaying it on a pop up window.
heres a reference https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/appid?topic=appid-single-page&interface=api

The docs say that App ID starts in a new window. AFAIK this is security best practice to show the user a familiar environment.
